# Is the sequence of events in SignalR guaranteed?

Tags: c#, javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

If I have a simple SignalR app that looks like this:

Client:

```
chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
};

...

var result = chat.server.send("Hello, World.");
console.log(result);
```

Server Hub:

```
public int Send(string message)
{
    Clients.All.addMessage(message);
    return 10;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
10
Hello, World.
```

I'm not entirely certain about what parts are working asynchronous magic and what parts are not, so I'd like to know if this order is guaranteed?

Is the return value of a server-side call guaranteed to arrive before any server-side push messages that that call may trigger?

Comment: This is more javascript related than anything else - whilst waiting for `send()` to complete, no other JS can run. After it finishes, the same block of JS executes (so, `log(result)`). It's only once you exit that block completely that any other JS can be executed. JS is single threaded.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. Just needed it confirmed. You might want to turn that comment into an answer...